# Removing brackets and numbers from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I am trying to remove the brackets from the list I have created but I am not sure how to go about doing this. I thought of doing replace() but this is a list object and so this would not work. How can I remove these tuple brackets and also the numbers? I have tried using isDigit() for number removal from the list but this does not seem to work. I get an error saying "tuple' object has no attribute 'isdigit"

```
movies = {'Spider-Man': 98, 'King Kong': 100}
displayMoviesForSort = list(movies.items())
displayMovies = sorted(displayMoviesForSort, key=lambda tup: (-tup[1],tup[0]))

print(displayMovies)
```

Output:

```
[('King Kong', 100), ('Spider-Man', 98)]
```

Desired output:

```
['King Kong', 100, 'Spider-Man', 98] #Removed brackets

['King Kong', 'Spider-Man'] #Removed numbers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `extend` to add all items from a `tuple` to a list:

```
displayMovies = [('King Kong', 100), ('Spider-Man', 98)]
noTuples = []
for item in displayMovies:
    noTuples.extend(item)
```

Output:

```
>>>noTuples
>>>['King Kong', 100, 'Spider-Man', 98]
```

Then you can use list comprehensions to remove numbers:

```
noNumbers = [item for item in noTuples if not isinstance(item, int)]
```

Output:

```
>>>noNumbers
>>>['King Kong', 'Spider-Man']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first case, removed brackets, by using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.

```
import itertools

movies = {'Spider-Man': 98, 'King Kong': 100}
sorted_movies = sorted(movies.items())
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sorted_movies))
```

The output will be `['Spider-Man', 98, 'King Kong', 100]`

You second case is simply `sorted(list(movies.keys()))`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `dict.keys`:

```
displayMoviesForSort = list(movies.keys())
>>>
['Spider-Man', 'King Kong']
```

Or:

```
#Removed brackets
flatList = [item for sublist in displayMoviesForSort for item in sublist]
flatList
>>>
['Spider-Man', 98, 'King Kong', 100]

#Removed numbers
flatList = flatList[::2]
flatList
>>>
['Spider-Man', 'King Kong']
```

Answer (score 1):

If your list content has some structure, e.g. items always of the form `(name, number)` you can use list comprehension and get it in one line:

```
displayMovies = [('King Kong', 100), ('Spider-Man', 98)]
print([name for name, _ in displayMovies])
```

This assumes tuples of the type `(name, number)`